# Postfix RPN Calculator debugging

Tags: java, postfix-notation

I'm trying to code a program to run a calculator using reverse polish notation and I have come across some problems, I have comments in the code explaining them so if someone could lend a helping hand it would be greatly appreciated!
 I know it has something to do with trying to acess position -1 in the stack but I can't seem to solve it.

```
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;


        public class Calculator {

            ArrayStack<Integer> stack;
            BufferedWriter out;
            public Calculator(BufferedWriter out) {
            this.out=out;
            }

            public void processLine( String line ) throws IOException {


                stack = new ArrayStack<>();
                String [] s = line.split ("\\s+");
                int operador1;
                int operador2; 
                int x=0;
                String operator;


            if (s[0].charAt(0)!='-'){     /if a string starts with a "-" it should be interpreted as a comment/
                if (isNumber(item)) {
                    int c = Integer.parseInt(item);
                    stack.push(c);
                } else {

                switch(item){ 

                    case "*":               /multiplies the last two entries in stack/
                        operador1= stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2*operador1);
                        break;

                    case "/":    /divides the last two entries in stack/
                        operador1= stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2/operador1);
                        break;

                    case "+":      /sums last two entries in stack/
                        operador1= stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2+operador1);
                        break;

                    case "-":    /subtracts last two entries in stack/
                        operador1= stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2-operador1);
                        break;

                    case "%":        /divides last two entries in stack/
                        operador1=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2%operador1);
                        break;

                    case ".":    /removes top of stack and writes in output file/
                        operador1=stack.peek();  /error here ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1/
                        stack.pop();
                        out.write(operador1);
                        out.newLine();
                        break;

                    case "@x":  /removes top of stack and puts it in x/
                        x= stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        break;

                    case "x":    /puts x in the stack's top/
                        stack.push(x);
                        break;

                    case "dup":  /repeats top of stack in stack/
                        operador1=stack.peek();
                        stack.push(operador1);
                        break;

                    case "swap": /swaps the last two entries/
                        operador1=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        operador2=stack.peek();
                        stack.pop();
                        stack.push(operador2);
                        stack.push(operador1);
                        break;

                    case "drop":   /remove top of stack/
                        stack.pop();


                }
                }
            }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
            }


            public boolean isNumber (String x){

        try{
                int y=Integer.parseInt(x);
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                return false;
            }

        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might have been a bit too quick in your cutting and pasting.
There are several things that are unclear with your code. It's hard to guess exactly
what you need help with, but here are some things you might want to clarify if you
want better help:

- You have mismatched number of brackets. I suspect the one before `System.out.println(" ");` is the one that should go.
- You don't iterate over the string array, you just look at it once. That looks suspicious.
  Even more so since you create a new `ArrayStack` for every invocation of `processLine` This
  makes it unclear if you intend to handle only one token at a time or all at once.
- You chosen syntax for comments seem to clash with the negation operator. I guess this
  could be okay if you want to handle all tokens at once since an operator can't be the
  first thing read, but it's not the best use of you symbols for ease of coding and debugging.
- The `item` variable is not defined anywhere.
- The `operator` variable is not used anywhere.
- You have no validation of the input string, are you assuming it will always be well
  formed? If so it would be good to also post the input it is failing for since there
  are several inputs where it is designed to fail.